# Is it possible to convert a wrongly done move in subversion to a true svn mv?

Tags: svn, addition, move

We have a subversion repository and just discovered that files in the subversion repository where moved from one folder to another using the filesystem operations resulting in a deletion and an addition to subversion. As expected history of the file was not taken over to the new location. 
Is it possible to convert this wrongly done move into a true svn mv where the history is copied along?
The problem is that the commit has been a while back and there have been several commits on top of this commit.  So a simple reverse merge and a proper move are out of option.

Comment: Why is a rollback out of options? The repository stores file changes, not more. That is something you can apply. So simply duplicate the repository (build a second one from a dump). Then roll back the first on to the last clean backup before that mistake. You can apply the changes inside the duplicated repository one by one to the content of the first repository. Just that single faulty revision should be replaced by a manual step. That works.

Comment: Because there have been over 100 commits above the revision which has to be changed and this would mean a lot of effort and some risk that a mistake is made along the way.

Comment: You certainly won't want to do those commits manually, certainly not. But you don't have to, you can do that all in one step since the revisions are stored inside the repository. You just have to apply them to the new repository in one go!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It is possible** assuming you have direct access to the repository, can dump and reload it, so assuming.

### In short the steps are:

1. [Dump the repository.](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html).
2. Modify the dump (see below).
3. [Create a new repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.create.html).
4. [Load the modified dump](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.load.html) into the new repository (loading the dump into the existing one would not replace the content, but actually be appended.
5. Verify the change.
6. Replace the old repository with the new repository.
   you need to dump the repository, modify the dump, delete, recreate and load the repository.

### Required Dumpfile Modification

Your wrong move operation in the dumpfile will look something like that:

```
Revision-number: 2
Prop-content-length: 111
Content-length: 111

K 7
svn:log
V 13
Wrong rename.
K 10
svn:author
V 3
tom
K 8
svn:date
V 27
2012-11-22T22:11:49.101403Z
PROPS-END

Node-path: renamed file.txt
Node-kind: file
Node-action: add
Prop-content-length: 10
Text-content-length: 8
Text-content-md5: 226648ec2921fddba76a340ac976f760
Text-content-sha1: 18cc7289b71fd17898ca179dcb3a05f3d2a07e8b
Content-length: 18

PROPS-END
Content!

Node-path: file.txt
Node-action: delete
```

For further reading the [dump file specification](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/dump-load-format.txt) is worth checking out, however for your problem only a small set of entries are relevant: There are two nodes, one with `Node-action: add`, the other with `Node-action: delete`. All you need to do is to modify the dump so that it looks like:

```
Revision-number: 2
Prop-content-length: 111
Content-length: 111

K 7
svn:log
V 13
Right rename.
K 10
svn:author
V 3
tom
K 8
svn:date
V 27
2012-11-22T22:13:51.674043Z
PROPS-END

Node-path: renamed file.txt
Node-kind: file
Node-action: add
Node-copyfrom-rev: 1
Node-copyfrom-path: file.txt
Text-copy-source-md5: 226648ec2921fddba76a340ac976f760
Text-copy-source-sha1: 18cc7289b71fd17898ca179dcb3a05f3d2a07e8b


Node-path: file.txt
Node-action: delete
```

Thus, you need *replace*

```
    Prop-content-length: <a>
    Text-content-length: <b>
    Text-content-md5: <md5>
    Text-content-sha1: <sha1>
    Content-length: <e>
```

with

```
    Node-copyfrom-rev: <correct revision>
    Node-copyfrom-path: <correct path>
    Text-copy-source-md5: <md5>
    Text-copy-source-sha1: <sha1>
```

and *remove* the actual content of the file.

The `delete` action stays unchanged.

Comment: Good, admirable job :) My answer would be simply "no, it's impossible" . Anyway, I have a feeling that this is verbose variation of that ;)

Comment: @Petr Kozelka: Thanks :-). Well, it can and has been done, but depending on the size of the dump it can take a quite some time.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought that I would have to do something like this. Seeing that the repository has something around 640000 revisions and that a large team is commiting to it I do not think it is worth the effort and the risk to do it like this. I was hoping there would be an easier way to do this.